# Where can I find the Metal Feature Set for the Apple M1?

Tags: macos, ipad, metal, ipados

I can't find any information about the M1 feature set - the M1 isn't listed here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/gpu_features/using_metal_feature_set_tables/

The M1 iPad isn't out yet but the M1 MacBooks are, so it seems critical information about the chip should be available somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what MoltenVK logs for the M1:

```
[mvk-info] GPU device:
        model: Apple M1
        type: Integrated
        vendorID: 0x106b
        deviceID: 0xa140
        pipelineCacheUUID: DDE1E551-0400-03EF-0000-000000000000
    supports the following Metal Versions, GPU's and Feature Sets:
        Metal Shading Language 2.3
        GPU Family Apple 7
        GPU Family Apple 6
        GPU Family Apple 5
        GPU Family Apple 4
        GPU Family Apple 3
        GPU Family Apple 2
        GPU Family Apple 1
        GPU Family Mac 2
        GPU Family Mac 1
        GPU Family Common 3
        GPU Family Common 2
        GPU Family Common 1
        macOS GPU Family 2 v1
        macOS GPU Family 1 v4
        macOS GPU Family 1 v3
        macOS GPU Family 1 v2
        macOS GPU Family 1 v1
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like they are just using the same GPU family as A14 for the M1, but I'm not convinced it isn't a new family - seems like it would be based on the chip specs.